# How do I prevent ElasticSearch (v7) from tokenizing synonyms with an edge_ngram tokenizer?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm basically trying to replicate the functionality of Google Places AutoComplete with ElasticSearch.

I have all places indexed on a single field, such as "Columbia, South Carolina 29044". The goal is to allow for autocomplete / typeahead functionality where if the user types "Columbia, SC", "2904", or "Columbia, South Carolina" then user is presented with the aforementioned option (assuming matching options are sparse enough for it to show).

The most obvious problem I'm running into right now is that the `synonym filter` is being tokenized and producing erroneous concoctions.

My index:

```js
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "stateAnalyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "synonymFilter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 30,
          "token_chars": ["letter", "digit"]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "synonymFilter": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "Florida,FL",
            "United States Virgin Islands,VI",
            "Montana,MT",
            "Minnesota,MN",
            "Maryland,MD",
            "South Carolina,SC",
            "Maine,ME",
            "Hawaii,HI",
            "District of Columbia,DC",
            "Commonwealth of the Northern Mariana Islands,MP",
            "Rhode Island,RI",
            "Nebraska,NE",
            "Washington,WA",
            "New Mexico,NM",
            "Puerto Rico,PR",
            "South Dakota,SD",
            "Texas,TX",
            "California,CA",
            "Alabama,AL",
            "Georgia,GA",
            "Arkansas,AR",
            "Pennsylvania,PA",
            "Missouri,MO",
            "Utah,UT",
            "Oklahoma,OK",
            "Tennessee,TN",
            "Wyoming,WY",
            "Indiana,IN",
            "Kansas,KS",
            "Idaho,ID",
            "Alaska,AK",
            "Nevada,NV",
            "Illinois,IL",
            "Vermont,VT",
            "Connecticut,CT",
            "New Jersey,NJ",
            "North Dakota,ND",
            "Iowa,IA",
            "New Hampshire,NH",
            "Arizona,AZ",
            "Delaware,DE",
            "Guam,GU",
            "American Samoa,AS",
            "Kentucky,KY",
            "Ohio,OH",
            "Wisconsin,WI",
            "Oregon,OR",
            "Mississippi,MS",
            "Colorado,CO",
            "North Carolina,NC",
            "Virginia,VA",
            "West Virginia,WV",
            "Louisiana,LA",
            "New York,NY",
            "Michigan,MI",
            "Massachusetts,MA"
          ],
          "expand": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "fullName": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "stateAnalyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "stateAnalyzer"
      },
      "route": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I analyze that with the following:

```js
{
  "analyzer": "stateAnalyzer", 
  "text": "columbia SC"
}
```

It produces, amongst others:

```js
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "co",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 2,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "co",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 2,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "col",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 3,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "col",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 3,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "colu",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "colo",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "colum",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 3
    },
    {
      "token" : "color",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 3
    },
    {
      "token" : "columb",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 4
    },
    {
      "token" : "colora",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 4
    },
    {
      "token" : "columbi",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 7,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 5
    },
    {
      "token" : "colorad",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 7,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 5
    },
    {
      "token" : "columbia",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 8,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 6
    },
    {
      "token" : "colorado",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 8,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 6
    },
    {
      "token" : "sc",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 7
    },
    {
      "token" : "so",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 7
    },
    {
      "token" : "sou",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 8
    },
    {
      "token" : "sout",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 9
    },
    {
      "token" : "south",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 10
    },
    {
      "token" : "ca",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 11
    },
    {
      "token" : "car",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 12
    },
    {
      "token" : "caro",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 13
    },
    {
      "token" : "carol",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 14
    },
    {
      "token" : "caroli",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 15
    },
    {
      "token" : "carolin",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 16
    },
    {
      "token" : "carolina",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 17
    }
  ]
}
```

The issue seems to be that as EaslticSearch is analyzing the text, it sees "**co**lum" which matches to the "Colorado,CO" synonym. However, I can't avoid this because setting the `min_gram: 3` results in the error `"term: FL was completely eliminated by analyzer"`

I guess breaking up the address into parts and indexing each field as a `completion` rather than `edge_ngram` on each part could resolve some of these issues. The challenge I have there is I don't know how I'd get highlighting to work. I currently have:

```js
{ 
  highlight: {
    fields: {
      fullName: {
        type: 'plain'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*edit:*

copy paste from kibana:

```
DELETE territories

PUT territories
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "stateAnalyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
          "filter": [
            "asciifolding",
            "lowercase",
            "synonymFilter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 30,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "synonymFilter": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "FL => Florida",
            "VI => United States Virgin Islands",
            "MT => Montana",
            "MN => Minnesota",
            "MD => Maryland",
            "SC => South Carolina",
            "ME => Maine",
            "HI => Hawaii",
            "DC => District of Columbia",
            "MP => Commonwealth of the Northern Mariana Islands",
            "RI => Rhode Island",
            "NE => Nebraska",
            "WA => Washington",
            "NM => New Mexico",
            "PR => Puerto Rico",
            "SD => South Dakota",
            "TX => Texas",
            "CA => California",
            "AL => Alabama",
            "GA => Georgia",
            "AR => Arkansas",
            "PA => Pennsylvania",
            "MO => Missouri",
            "UT => Utah",
            "OK => Oklahoma",
            "TN => Tennessee",
            "WY => Wyoming",
            "IN => Indiana",
            "KS => Kansas",
            "ID => Idaho",
            "AK => Alaska",
            "NV => Nevada",
            "IL => Illinois",
            "VT => Vermont",
            "CT => Connecticut",
            "NJ => New Jersey",
            "ND => North Dakota",
            "IA => Iowa",
            "NH => New Hampshire",
            "AZ => Arizona",
            "DE => Delaware",
            "GU => Guam",
            "AS => American Samoa",
            "KY => Kentucky",
            "OH => Ohio",
            "WI => Wisconsin",
            "OR => Oregon",
            "MS => Mississippi",
            "CO => Colorado",
            "NC => North Carolina",
            "VA => Virginia",
            "WV => West Virginia",
            "LA => Louisiana",
            "NY => New York",
            "MI => Michigan",
            "MA => Massachusetts"
          ],
          "expand": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "fullName": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "stateAnalyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "stateAnalyzer"
      },
      "route": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST territories/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "stateAnalyzer", 
  "text": "columbia SC"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this with explicit synonym mappings? If your data is indexed uniformly with `South Carolina` and not `SC`, you can explicitly map `SC` to `South Carolina`.

Comment: It's not occurring actually. Are you sure that analyse produced that output?

Comment: @IanGabes I'm not familiar with explicit synonym mappings. I'll look them up. Thanks.

Comment: @Gibbs yes, I updated it with the full list. Your initial answer was right in that it is breaking up Columbia to -> Co, Col, which the Co is a synonym for Colorado. I just don't know how to explicitly state not to do that in the scenario where CO is followed by a letter. I'm going to look up explicit synonyms as per IanGabes recommendation.

Comment: @IanGabes actually, i think the same problem would occur though where the ngram is breaking up the input and picking up the synonyms, right?

Columbia -> **CO** [matches synonym Colorado], Col,... Carolina -> **CA** [matches synonym California], Car, Carol

Comment: @Chance I am still not able to reproduce. Something is missing in your question/findings. Edge engram is fine. But mixing synonyms is not happening actually

Comment: @Gibbs I updated my question with a copy/paste directly from kibana.

Comment: @IanGabes yea, same thing happens with explicit synonyms.

Comment: Ngram is causing the issue @Chance.

Comment: @Chance I think you want to invert those mappings such that `CA => California`

Comment: @IanGabes When flipped, they don't trigger the synonyms.

    ```{ "token" : "sc", "start_offset" : 9, "end_offset" : 11, "type" : "word", "position" : 7 }```

Comment: @Gibbs yea, that's kind of what I assumed as well. I just don't know how to resolve it. I have all of the data necessary to break it apart into multiple fields (ie, city, state, zip) but don't know how to fold it all back in to a singular result with highlighting. Using `completion` without unfolding the data would mean that I can't search on '29210'.  Thank you for taking the time to look into it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I think we are able to achieve this if we re-order the analyzer a bit based on my current understanding. If we postpone generating the Edge Ngrams until after tokenization, we can ensure that we are only tokenizing terms that we are interested in auto-completing.

`Columbia SC` will transform into: `["Columbia", "South", "Carolina"]` (before edge-ngramming). `SC` will never make it into the inverted index, only the fully qualified terms, even though `SC` is still searchable.

Here is your updated analyzer:

```
PUT territories
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "stateAnalyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "asciifolding",
            "lowercase",
            "synonymFilter",
            "edge_ngram_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "edge_ngram_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 5,
          "preserve_original": true
        },
        "synonymFilter": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "FL => Florida",
            "VI => United States Virgin Islands",
            "MT => Montana",
            "MN => Minnesota",
            "MD => Maryland",
            "SC => South Carolina",
            "ME => Maine",
            "HI => Hawaii",
            "DC => District of Columbia",
            "MP => Commonwealth of the Northern Mariana Islands",
            "RI => Rhode Island",
            "NE => Nebraska",
            "WA => Washington",
            "NM => New Mexico",
            "PR => Puerto Rico",
            "SD => South Dakota",
            "TX => Texas",
            "CA => California",
            "AL => Alabama",
            "GA => Georgia",
            "AR => Arkansas",
            "PA => Pennsylvania",
            "MO => Missouri",
            "UT => Utah",
            "OK => Oklahoma",
            "TN => Tennessee",
            "WY => Wyoming",
            "IN => Indiana",
            "KS => Kansas",
            "ID => Idaho",
            "AK => Alaska",
            "NV => Nevada",
            "IL => Illinois",
            "VT => Vermont",
            "CT => Connecticut",
            "NJ => New Jersey",
            "ND => North Dakota",
            "IA => Iowa",
            "NH => New Hampshire",
            "AZ => Arizona",
            "DE => Delaware",
            "GU => Guam",
            "AS => American Samoa",
            "KY => Kentucky",
            "OH => Ohio",
            "WI => Wisconsin",
            "OR => Oregon",
            "MS => Mississippi",
            "CO => Colorado",
            "NC => North Carolina",
            "VA => Virginia",
            "WV => West Virginia",
            "LA => Louisiana",
            "NY => New York",
            "MI => Michigan",
            "MA => Massachusetts"
          ],
          "expand": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "fullName": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "stateAnalyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "stateAnalyzer"
      },
      "route": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you are interested in auto-complete, using suggesters is probably where you are going to end up. Here is what a sample query and output might look like using the above analyzer.

Query:

```
POST territories/_doc/
{
  "fullName": "Columbia, South Carolina 29044"
}

POST territories/_doc/
{
  "fullName": "Myrtle Beach, South Carolina 90210"
}

GET territories/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "match": {
      "fullName": "Columbia SC"
    }
  },
  "suggest" : {
    "my-suggestion" : {
      "text" : "Columbia SC",
      "term" : {
        "field" : "fullName"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query output:

```
...
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "territories",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6LyxTnMBxDBOJM21waus",
        "_score" : 2.1154594,
        "_source" : {
          "fullName" : "Columbia, South Carolina 29044"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "territories",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ury0TnMBxDBOJM21VrAj",
        "_score" : 0.7175633,
        "_source" : {
          "fullName" : "Myrtle Beach, South Carolina 90210"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "suggest" : {
    "my-suggestion" : [
      {
        "text" : "co",
        "offset" : 0,
        "length" : 8,
        "options" : [ ]
      },
      {
        "text" : "col",
        "offset" : 0,
        "length" : 8,
        "options" : [ ]
      },
      {
        "text" : "colu",
        "offset" : 0,
        "length" : 8,
        "options" : [ ]
      },
      {
        "text" : "colum",
        "offset" : 0,
        "length" : 8,
        "options" : [ ]
      },
      {
        "text" : "columbia",
        "offset" : 0,
        "length" : 8,
        "options" : [ ]
      },
      {
        "text" : "so",
        "offset" : 9,
        "length" : 2,
        "options" : [ ]
      },
      {
        "text" : "sou",
        "offset" : 9,
        "length" : 2,
        "options" : [ ]
      },
      {
        "text" : "sout",
        "offset" : 9,
        "length" : 2,
        "options" : [ ]
      },
      {
        "text" : "south",
        "offset" : 9,
        "length" : 2,
        "options" : [ ]
      },
      {
        "text" : "ca",
        "offset" : 9,
        "length" : 2,
        "options" : [ ]
      },
      {
        "text" : "car",
        "offset" : 9,
        "length" : 2,
        "options" : [ ]
      },
      {
        "text" : "caro",
        "offset" : 9,
        "length" : 2,
        "options" : [ ]
      },
      {
        "text" : "carol",
        "offset" : 9,
        "length" : 2,
        "options" : [ ]
      },
      {
        "text" : "carolina",
        "offset" : 9,
        "length" : 2,
        "options" : [ ]
      }
    ]
...
```

You can see the effective equivalent of your `_analyze` endpoint there, under the `suggest` field.

Comment: As a small aside, seeing `Commonwealth of the Northern Mariana Islands` was a small learning experience on its own! Had never heard of it ; )

Comment: You're awesome man. That's exactly what I was wondering if were possible! 

I actually started this with a suggester but couldn't figure out how to go about handling zip codes, for example. Everything is stored as `[city], [state] [zip]` so a suggester wouldn't pick up on a query for '29212'.

I'm with you though, I think a suggester makes the most sense. 

Even though this is leaps and bounds better than where I was, it still isn't ideal for typeahead autocompletes. A query of "Columbia, S" has 2 results:

["S Coffeyville, Oklahoma 74072", "U S A F Academy, Colorado 80840"

Comment: Also, that's awesome. I had no idea either until I pulled in all of the census data.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I thought I had dropped the min_gram down to 1 but I was mistaken. This is going to have to be good enough until I figure out how to properly handle a `suggest` that highlights and can account for zip codes.

Comment: Thanks again. This definitely helped a ton!